# Trying to create a 'polling' service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've come to a conclusion that I am not able to create a polling service that I can consume in my components. It follows my local function within a component typescript code that makes use of a global data service that makes a get request (i.e. `dataService.getDetailedOrdersForBP(...)`).

my-component.ts

```
pollOrders(intervalTime?: number, orderId?: string) {
    console.log('pollOrders');
    const time = intervalTime ? intervalTime : environment.pollingTime;
    const id = orderId ? orderId : '';
    this.subscription = TimerObservable.create(0, time)
        .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.dataService.getDetailedOrdersForBP(this.credentials.username, this.credentials.llp, '1', '7988', id)
            subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.detailedOrders = data.orders;
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
}
```

My question is whether I can move this `TimerObservable` code that does the polling to my global service. All my attempts so far were unsuccessful. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you say what is current behavior of your code? Is it running? Is it running once? What's the problem?

Comment: @aledpardo No problem with my code. The above function is placed inside a component and does the polling of my 'getDetailedOrdersForBP' in the given interval time. My question is whether I could place this polling mechanism of TimerObservable to another function inside my global service and calling this instead, in order to get the data.

Comment: So you are trying to combine both actions: the timer and the API call, right? You could combine them using the `zip` from observables

Comment: Could you give an example? Even if I use `zip` to combine these 2 observables, I'm not sure how I can consume this combination returned by `zip` to get data in my component

Answer (score 0):

So, seems like you need a [hot observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339).

I would suggest you to create a new component service (a kind of you global service).

On this service you start your polling using the hot observable approach.

Then, you subscribe to this observable on each component you need to listen for polling data.

Comment: My API that makes the GET request, returns an Observable. Hot observables approach could apply to my case if TimerObservable.create(..) returned an Observable too. But, instead, it subscribes to the GET request Observable and handles its data